# How can I output a specific field in Sprout Forms email notifications?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to override a Sprout Forms email notification template. The example template loops over tabs and fields and outputs them all, that works. I'd like to manually reference specific fields in specific places (like first_name). How can I reach the field values?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, there's an `element` twig variable that I can use (it contains the Sprout Form entry), so I can output:

```
{{ element.first_name }}
```

for instance.